# prove $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

prove$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ if $A_i$ is a arbitrary set and $B_1=A_1$ and $B_n=A_n-\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$ for $n\ge 2$.

I have no ideas for solving it there was another question befor this that wanted to show:

$A_n\cap[A_n\cup B_n]=A_n$ that was easy to solve because $A_n\cup B_n=B_n$ and then $B_n \cap A_n=A_n$.I wrote this because I think it may helpful.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do you really mean $A_i$ is a **random set**?  The term "random set"  has a deep and subtle definition.  Besides, the theorem is true if the $A_i$ are arbitrary sets.  I think that must be what you mean.

Comment: Also, your second lquestion is done incorrectly:  $A_u \cup B_n = A_n$ is not in general true. You meant to say $A_n \cup B_n \supseteq A_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start: The right-hand side is clearly a subset of the left-hand side, because $B_n\subseteq A_n$.

To show that the left-hand side is a subset of the right-hand side, pick an element $x$ of the left-hand side. Then there is a smallest $n$ such that $x\in A_n$. Use this to show $x$ is in the RHS.

Comment: .But this is and equality this shows just $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$

Comment: For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, ${{B}_{n}}\subseteq {{A}_{n}}$

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki.Do you sy this is a proof by induction?

Comment: :D André Nicolas' answer is nice.

Comment: We could prove by induction that $\bigcup_1^m A_k=\bigcup_1^m B_k$. The proof I outlined uses the least number principle, so in a sense induction, but there is no real need to make the induction formal.

Comment: .......Nice +1.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can see why this is intuitively clear: you are essentially constructing the $B_n$'s so that they are disjoint and their union is that of the $A_n$'s.

To prove the claim formally: $\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is clear. Let $x \in \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Consider the set $S_x = \{n: x \in A_n\}$. By the well-ordering principle $S_x$ has a least element, say $n_0$. Then $x \not \in A_n$ for all $n<n_0$ so $x\in B_{n_0}$. From here we get the right inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim 1:** $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.

*Proof:* Pick any $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$. Then, there exists some $n^*\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in B_{n^*}$. Since $B_n\subseteq A_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ by construction, it follows that $x\in A_{n^*}\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. $\blacksquare$

> **Claim 2:** $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$.

*Proof:* Suppose that $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Then, there exists some $n^*\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in A_{n^*}$. Define $n^{\circ}$ as the *least* positive integer satisfying $x\in A_{n^{\circ}}$. Formally, $$n^{\circ}\equiv\min\{n\in\mathbb N\,|\,x\in A_n\}.$$ Note that the set over which the minimum is taken is not empty since it contains $n^*$.

If, on the one hand, $n^{\circ}=1$, then $A_{n^{\circ}}=B_{n^{\circ}}$, so that  $x\in B_{n^{\circ}}$.

On the other hand, if $n^{\circ}\geq 2$, then, by the definition of $n^{\circ}$, $x$ is *not* contained in $A_n$ for any $n\in\{1,\ldots, n^{\circ}-1\}$, but it is contained in $A_{n^{\circ}}$. Formally, $$x\in A_{n^{\circ}}-\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n^{\circ}-1}A_i\right)=B_{n^{\circ}}.$$ In either case, $x\in B_{n^{\circ}}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way to make the main claim.  If $x\in\bigcup_n A_n$, by well-ordering of the integers, we know there is a smallest $n$ so that $x\in A_n$. Then $$x\in A_n - \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k = B_n.$$